# Instant Run requires 'Tools | Android | Enable ADB integration' to be enabled

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio

In the Default settings Instant Run is enabled but I can't find the actual problem behind it. 
Please Help

I am using Android Studio 2.0 on ubuntu 14.04 
If I disabled the first option in settings then it takes time to build app

How to Proceed ???[image]

Thank You

Comment: Better Answer can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37718739/error-running-app-instant-run-requires-tools-android-enable-adb-integratio

Answer (score 106, accepted):

[image]

menu>> tools>>Android>>Enable ADB integration   check it 。

Comment: Do I have to this every time I open the IDE?

Comment: No you don't have to do it every time

Comment: I wonder why **ADB Integration** is not enabled by default in Android Studio.  Seems rudimentary to do so...

Comment: Worked Solution :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37718739/error-running-app-instant-run-requires-tools-android-enable-adb-integratio

Answer (score 8):

You also need to close DDMS (if it is opened).

Comment: Why it is so? Please let us know the reason how its related and affects the run

Comment: How do we "close DDMS"? I'm in the Android Device Monitor and I can't find the option to do it (DDMS is listed but not clickable).