# Android Studio: Instant Run Issue

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-instant-run

I have installed Android Studio 2.1 (stable version) on linux mint system. When I am installing a simple App, I am getting the message:

Instant Run requires 'Tools | Android | Enable ADB integration' to be enabled.

I already have this option enabled on my Android Studio. Please help me resolving this issue.

Any help would be appreciated.. !!!

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526353/instant-run-requires-tools-android-enable-adb-integration-to-be-enabled

Comment: Go to Tools -> Android -> Check Enable ADB Integration to fix this issue :)