# Android studio's adb is ignored for running the android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, genymotion, expo

I have a react native project using expo. I can run the IOS simulator using, which works fine

```
npm run ios
```

I have also installed Android Studio and it has the required sdks and other stuff as required in the react native documentation. Also, I have installed Genymotion for the android emulator and changed the **adb** section to custom directory to the Android studio's director where the sdk is, which is located in (**/Users/robin/library/android/sdk**).

However, I can't run the android simulator. If I run this command:

```
npm run android
```

I get an error:

> Error running adb: No Android device found. Please connect a device and follow the instructions here to enable USB debugging:
>   https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html#developer-device-options. If you are using Genymotion go to Settings -> ADB, select "Use custom Android SDK tools", and point it at your Android SDK directory.

So I checked where the adb is running from:

```
$ which adb
/usr/local/bin/adb
```

However, the adb of Android studio is located in

```
/Users/robin/library/android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
```

I think Android studio's adb is not running for the emulator. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Check this answer it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/37719213/2599596

Comment: @NaveenKumarM That didn't helped me. ADB integration is already enabled.

Answer (score 3):

I don't want to admit how many hours I spent on this, but it looks like you have everything configured correctly. (For anyone else confused about the config options, see the Expo [documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v18.0.0/guides/genymotion.html) for Genymotion.)

When using `yarn start ios`, an iOS simulator is automatically started for you and your app will run. However, when using `yarn start android`, a Genymotion virtual device is not automatically started for you. So, open Genymotion, and make sure you have a virtual device. If you don't have any yet, hit the + icon and add one. Then start it. Now go back to your terminal and run `yarn start android`.

I know this question is almost three weeks old so hopefully you were able to sort everything out, but I thought I'd chime in just in case anyone else runs into this problem.