# Android Studio does not recognize my phone

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I would be so, so grateful for help with this.

My phone: Lenovo P2
Phone OS: 7.0 Nougat
PC OS: Windows 8.1

I have installed Android Studio.
I have switched on Developer Options on my phone.
I have set USB debugging to on.
I have plugged my phone by USB to my PC.
My PC recognises it, I can view and move phone files from the PC

When I hit the green play button in Android Studio, it does not find my phone.
I have searched for a driver for my phone (described in the Udacity Google Android course I am taking) but Lenovo provide no driver for it (even though their link is listed on Google's USB Driver page). Not sure if I even need this driver if my computer can recognize my phone already?

I saw another similiar question on Stack Overflow where the question asker realized that USB debugging was switching off when he plugged in the USB. He had to remember to switch it back on each time after plugging in the USB. That is not the problem here, USB debugging remains switched on throughout.

Comment: Did you install USB drivers from Google ? https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb.html (Your OS may recognize your device as an external storage only, and you may need these drivers for ADB).

Comment: Thanks Jerome, I have installed the driver from that link to my Windows PC. I have unzipped the file. Do I need to do anything else to get it working? (I have tried Device Manager and located the folder it is in but my system does not recognize the driver as being for my phone)

Comment: When you plug in your phone to a PC with debugging enabled you should be getting a "Allow this PC" message, if you don't accept it will not show up in Android studio, did you accept that?

Comment: HI XabinCoffee, yes I get that message and I accept it each time I plug into the USB.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help yesterday. This morning I found an old Samsung phone on which Android Studio works perfectly, so problem (at least for me) is solved. Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

If you are on Ubuntu
Go to terminal.
Type the following:
sudo -s

adb devices

That's it.

Now run from the studio.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Shyju, however I am running Windows 8.1

Comment: Ok. Try adb devices from cmd . Open cmd  as administrator. I think it will help. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks again man. I have opened cmd as an administrator then typed in adb devices      The result is just "'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: Refer this link to add adb to environmental variables. 
 https://www.howtodroid.com/2014/02/how-to-add-adb-command-prompt-windows.html

Comment: Have you already installed adb and is it enabled in android studio?

Comment: I can see ADB in Device Manager but not sure if it is enabled in Android Studio. Do you know how I can check if it is enabled in Android Studio?

Comment: I followed the 7 steps of directions on howtodroid (your link). Now when I type in adb devices the following message appears: List of devices attached. -----but there is no device/s listed underneath.

Comment: In android studio goto tools then android..and there u will find an option to enable adb in studio. I guess that's
 how we can enable adb.

Comment: When I select Tools, there is a dropdown list of option but none is "Android". According to this link, Android should be an option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37718739/error-running-app-instant-run-requires-tools-android-enable-adb-integratio     Maybe the screenshot is from an older version of Android Studio. I installed the version available today from their website.

Comment: Build your project at first then only android will show up

Comment: Thanks again Shyju, I have selected "Build" and then "Rebuild Project" from the dropdown. The rebuild has finished... still no Android option in the dropdown when I select "Tools" from the top of the screen.

Comment: @WarriorMonkIRE  It should show up once successfully built. Don't know why its not showing in your case.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help anyway. I'll ask people at Google+ developer support.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help yesterday. This morning I found an old Samsung phone on which Android Studio works perfectly, so problem (at least for me) is solved. Thank you :)

Comment: Great...Happy to hear that