# Android studio app run error for virtual device

Tags: android, android-studio

When I develop an app, I use a virtual machine but when I run the app it gives an error message that says

> Instant Run requires 'Tools |Android| Enable ADB integration' to be enabled.

What should I do?

Comment: Did you try going to tools - android - then enabling ADB integration?

Comment: a simple google search yields top 4 answers from stackoverflow.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error running app: Instant Run requires 'Tools | Android | Enable ADB integration' to be enabled.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37718739/error-running-app-instant-run-requires-tools-android-enable-adb-integratio)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instant Run requires 'Tools | Android | Enable ADB integration' to be enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526353/instant-run-requires-tools-android-enable-adb-integration-to-be-enabled)

Comment: Try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37718739/error-running-app-instant-run-requires-tools-android-enable-adb-integratio

Answer (score 1):

You can do it according to the picture,and choose the Enable ADB Integration.

[image]